# Containing a text_area inside a well class in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a form for my Rails app and I am having a hard time containing the actual `<%= f.text_area %>` form helper. I am using TB and my text area is not aligning properly to its parent element, the `div class="well>`. Any help? I want the form to be nicely center inside the `well`class. Here is what I've got.

```
<div class="well">
    <%= form_for [@post, @comment] do |f| %>
      <div class="control-group">
        <%= f.text_area :body, class: "span12", rows: "7", placeholder: "Comment goes here" %>
      </div>

      <%= f.submit "Create comment", class: "btn btn-primary" %> 
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

And right now the form helper is slightly outside of the `well`.

Comment: specify span12 on the class itself, span12 is the largest you can go with bootstrap, then maybe something smaller with the text area

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add some padding around the text area that way it should increase the size of the well with it or manually override the well in your css to increase it's size so that the form helper fits nicely inside.